# How to properly name a restful url of an api to sync info from external service?

Tags: rest

I have a resource, userResource.
There already has a function to edit it, route to '/api/user', put method.
Besides, a function needed to sync userResourceInfo from other service,
I don't know how to name the route of the sync function.
Could anyone know how to deal this situation?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: To sum it up, you have one of your own functions that you are running on `/api/user` but you have one more which is external, which you'd like to access it separately from your `/api/user` endpoint?

Answer (score 1):

Think about your resources (the R in REST). You already have users. Now we introduce a second resource, let's call it **UserInfoSynchronization**. An instance of this resource represents a single synchronization of user information.

The base URL for this resource could be the collection of all UserInfoSynchronization: `/api/UserInfoSynchronization`:

- `GET` this URL will return the list of all existing UserInfoSynchronization instances.
- `POST` to this URL will create a *new* UserInfoSynchronization. To identify the user the sychronization applies to, a JSON body could be the request body: `{"user": "user-1"}`. The response to this request would include a `Location` header with the URL to the creatred UserInfoSynchronization: `Location: /api/UserInfoSynchronization/14870257-681e-4eef-b0f8-cbaf4f578819`
- `GET /api/UserInfoSynchronization/14870257-681e-4eef-b0f8-cbaf4f578819` would return the current state of the UserInfoSynchronization, for example `{"user": "user-1", "state": "synchronizing"}` or `{"user": "user-1", "state": "finished"}` and maybe additional information like timestamps.
- `DELETE /api/UserInfoSynchronization/14870257-681e-4eef-b0f8-cbaf4f578819` would cancel the UserInfoSynchronization.

Note that none of these calls actually executes the synchronization. You would need some background service that notices the new UserInfoSynchronization, executes it, and sets its state.